# Dynamic Object in c++ doesn't work

Tags: c++, class, object, dynamic

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class STRING {
    private:
        char *S[10];
    public:
        STRING();
        void set_str(int n, const char* str1);
        char* get_str(int n);
};

STRING :: STRING(){
    for (int i=0; (i < 9); i ++ ){
        S[i] = '\0';
        cout <<  S[i];
    }

}
void STRING :: set_str(int n,const char*str1) {
    S[n] = (char*)malloc(strlen(str1 + 1));
    strcpy(S[n], str1);
    cout << S[n];
}
char* STRING :: get_str(int n){
    return S[n];
}

int main () {

    cout << " Init \n";
    STRING* str = new STRING();
    cout << "Error \n";
return 0;
```

This program compiles successfully, runs, but when it runs it only works before the inicialization of object **STRING* str = new STRING();**. So I can't see in this case **Error** message. Could someone point me my mistake, please?
And if there is a better way to initialize the array of strings, I would be happy to know.

My goal is to initialize tha array of stings. And initially set values of the whole array to NULL.
Regards

Comment: Why reinventing the wheel? you already have a happy `string` class, also you shouldn't be using `malloc` if you're really writing a C++ code.

Comment: also, please take this into consideration: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6555/To-new-is-C-To-malloc-is-C-To-mix-them-is-sin

Comment: You should look into std::vector<std::string>.

Comment: im not allowed to use string type

Comment: "I'm not allowed to use string type":  is this homework?  There's nothing wrong with asking homework-related questions on StackOverflow, but it's considered good form to tag the question as such.

Comment: yes, it is a part of hw. ok, ill tag it

Answer (score 2):

Assuming STRING means "a collection of 10 strings", then it's your constructor.  You are setting the pointers to the value of the character '\0' and not to a null pointer.  You're assigning a char type to a char* type.  Now that may work, but then you have the cout statement.  And it tries to DEREFERENCE the pointer.  But the pointer is pointing to wherever in memory '\0' is, not a null character at that point.

Edit:  In response to the OP's question, here's how I think it should be done for initializing to 10 empty char arrays.  Your constructor will change to:

```
STRING :: STRING(){
    for (int i=0; i < 10; i ++ ){ // changed to 10.  9 would miss the 10th element
        S[i] = new char[1]; // Length-1 char array
        S[i][0] = 0; // or '/0' or whatever
        cout <<  S[i];  // Prints nothing
    }
}
```

Also you need a destructor to free the memory:

STRING::STRING~()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        delete [] S[i];
}

And change your "set" method to use "new" and not "malloc".  Or everything to malloc and free.  But don't mix them.  And remember to use "array delete" and not just delete.

And FTLOG, go to and bookmark [this link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp).  Use the built-in string class.

Comment: OK. Thank you. In this case, how to initialize all array's entry to '\0' ?

Answer (score 0):

The correct declaration of the member should be:

```
 char S[10];
```

The way you have it

```
 char *S[10];
```

declares an array of 10 `char *`. So when you do `S[i] = '\0';`, you're initializing `S[i]`, which is a pointer to a `char`, to `'\0'`, which is probably NULL, so you're basically calling `cout << NULL` on the next line.

Comment: He is not trying to make 1 'char array'. he is trying to make a pointer to a char array with 10 indices. Thus saving 10 strings in an array. See his 'set_str' method

Comment: @DaanTimmer and that's why it's wrong. The assignment `S[i]='\0';` makes no sense.

Comment: You didn't write that when I downvoted ;-) Thus your initial answer was wrong. Hence the downvote :-) Anyway, there is much more wrong with the code then just that part. Will undo downvote.

Comment: Yes, there is indeed a lot wrong.  malloc being another thing that while legal, isn't "good" for a habit in C++.  And it will also leak memory (mallocs, but no "free").  And probably more besides.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore +1; Indeed, no need to bash on the messenger. He operates on S (an array of 10 char pointers) in one part as if it is just a simple character array, null-terminating pointers (the hell?) and in the other part he tinkers with memory manually and treats the declaration a little bit better (but still zero sense). And he doesn't even release.

Comment: Your suggestion of a "correct declaration" is just as wrong as his existing declaration given the rest of the code the class includes.

Comment: OK. Could someone give a code to declare an array of lenght ten with srings in entries? and set initial strings value? to NULL?

Comment: @user1322731 Set it to NULL or 0. And don't try to output NULL pointers (they don't point to any strings YET). And match malloc calls with proper memory release code (good memory management).

Comment: And evade mallocs for the love of all that is sacred.